# Make two methods run one after another in thread while using synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have written a demo code for Atm machine while using synchronization

```
class Atm{
    synchronized void checkBalance(String str){
        System.out.print(str+" is checking his ");
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Balance ");
    }
    synchronized void withdraw(String str, int amt){
        System.out.print(str+ " is withdrawing amount: ");
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println(amt);
    }
}

class Customer extends Thread{
    String name;
    int amt;
    Atm a;
    Customer (Atm a){
        this.a=a;
    }

    public void useAtm(){
        a.checkBalance(name);
        a.withdraw(name,amt);
    }
    public void run(){
        useAtm();
    }
}
```

after running the main method i get the output as [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pW5e.png) where as soon as the thread 1 after releasing checkBalance, goes to withdraw method but thread 2 gets access to check balance before thread 1 could get monitor on withdraw and i get the output as such.
But on other cases i get the output as: [Output 2 in order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8udd.png)... where the threads access the methods one after another. How can i make sure that thread 2 or any other thread doesn't access checkBalance till thread 1 has completed accessing both checkBalance and withdraw?

Basically how to make the output as "Ram checks, Ram withdraws, S checks, S withdraws...." instead of "R checks, S checks, S withdraws, R withdraws"

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        Atm a=new Atm();
        Customer c1=new Customer(a);
        Customer c2=new Customer(a);
        Customer c3=new Customer(a);

        c1.name="Ram";
        c1.amt=5000;

        c2.name="Hari";
        c2.amt=51000;

        c3.name="Shyam";
        c3.amt=545000;

        Customer c4=new Customer(a);
        Customer c5=new Customer(a);
        Customer c6=new Customer(a);

        c4.name="xam";
        c4.amt=500220;

        c5.name="pari";
        c5.amt=5100220;

        c6.name="ohyam";
        c6.amt=54501200;

        c1.start();
        c2.start();
        c3.start();
        c4.start();
        c5.start();
        c6.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: If you're just doing a simple extension of the existing, then try extending the time the monitor is held - i.e. `syncronized (a) { a.checkBalance(); a.withDraw() }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you did try to synchronize functions individually, which make sense if you want to use them separately synchronized. But when you want two functions to run in a synchronized way try using

```
      public void useAtm(){
              synchronized(a){
              a.checkBalance(name);
              a.withdraw(name,amt);
       }
     }
```

which will solve your problem. Try removing synchronized tag to methods.

```
    void checkBalance(String str){
    void withdraw(String str, int amt){
```

I hope it solved your issue.